# Passing one Prop vs Many Props vs Nested Components in React?

Tags: reactjs

This is a part of **[Think in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)**.

Thinking in React is the hard part for me because I see many developers do React with different mindsets.

When I was writing code for the `Notification` component that will be used by developers, suddenly I've noticed that there are different experiences to use the component:

**Passing many Props like `Bootstrap`**

```
  <Notification 
        title="New Feature"
        body={message}
        action={action}/>
```

**Passing one Prop as an Object**

```
  const data = {
  title:"",
  subtitle:"",
  message:""
  }
  <Notification data={data}/>
```

**Passing nested Children**

```
   <Notification>
   <Title></Title>
   <Body><Body/>
   <Action><Action>
   </Notification>
```

I followed the passing nested Children because ( I guess)  It seems if I scale the component, I don't need to provide a `Bootstrap-like` experience for the developers.

```
import React from "react"
import { Wrapper, Text } from "./Styled"

const Body = ({ message }) => (
    <Wrapper>
        <Text>{message}</Text>
    </Wrapper>
)

export default Body
```

The problem is I'm thinking about it is when I want to scale the Component and let's say adding 3 additional features that require 3 additional `props`

I'm confused about the reasons *why* each approach might be chosen, and what's the "best" developer experience.

Comment: The reasons you'd expect--how much control is required.

Comment: What do you want to own the rendering of theses pieces?  The first means that the `Notification` receives props and owns the rendering of them.  The second means that you have 3 additional components that will be responsible for rendering and receiving data.  Which to use, is opinion based as it will vary by use case.

Comment: Can you show how `actions` and `message` look like, because it depends

Comment: @DennisVash , message a `<p>` and action is a `<button>`.

Comment: I mean, how do you render it, action = <button>...</button> or as a function, everything depends in this question, need a little bit more context

Comment: @DaveNewton, please could you clarify more.

Comment: If you want to provide fine-grained control you use sub-components. If you want everything wrapped up you don’t.

Comment: There's no reason to (a) shout about this not being an opinion-based question or (b) update the *question* with your own solution. SO isn't really the best place for "why might I do this" type questions. And you explicitly made it opinion-based by asking for what's "best": there is no general "best" approach.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question let's review all possibilities given [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) and a [Function Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#hooks-and-function-components):

```
const c1 = <div>React Element</div>;
const C2 = () => <div>Function Component</div>;
```

Notice that from performance perspective, every component can be memoized and not cause useless renders.

---

### Pass React element through props

```
const ObjectProps = ({ component }) => {
  console.log("render object props");
  return component;
};
<ObjectProps component={c1} />
```

#### Pros

- Simple.
- Lets you define the exact usage of passed component (contract).

  - For example you might decide "messages" have to be on top of "actions"

#### Cons

- No lazy rendering

  - Passing heavy component may cause performance issues.
- Hard to inject props (need to use `React.cloneElement`).

  - As a library writer you would like to inject your styles and refs.

---

### Passing Function Component

```
const FunctionComponentProps = ({ FunctionComponent }) => {
  console.log("render function component");
  return <FunctionComponent />;
};
<FunctionComponentProps FunctionComponent={C2} />
```

#### Pros

- Lazy rendering.
- Easy to pass props and inject props for inner implementation.
- Lets you define the exact usage of passed component (contract).

#### Cons

- Confusing

---

### Children Render

```
const ChildrenRender = ({ children }) => {
  console.log("render function component");
  return children;
};

<ChildrenRender>
  {c1}
  <C2 />
</ChildrenRender>
```

#### Pros

- No restriction for the developer (no contract)

#### Cons

- Hard to inject children (need to use `React.Children` API + `React.cloneElement` combo)
- No contract

  - The developer might pass "buttons" and then "messages" and break the view.

Implementing `ChildrenRender` usually comes with component instances which results a minimal "contract" mentioned above.

```
const ChildrenRender = ({ children }) => {...};
ChildrenRender.InnerComp1 = <SomeComponent .../>
ChildrenRender.InnerComp2 = <SomeComponent2 .../>

<ChildrenRender>
  <ChildrenRender.InnerComp1>{c1}</ChildrenRender.InnerComp1>
  <ChildrenRender.InnerComp2><C2/></ChildrenRender.InnerComp2>
</ChildrenRender>
```

### In Conclusion

It heavily depends on the component's usage, usually the hybrid approach suits well - passing components through props and add an option for passing `children` too.

> Another technique is [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

Comment: In fact,  I'm not passing `Components` as a `Props` but I'm just confusing between passing one Prop to the parent then let children consume it through `Context` or pass `properties` for each component. I've reformated the question, please take a look again.

Comment: You should spread the object to multiple props, mostly because it gives you more options when the component scales